# Python - Pyramid of letters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a pyramid like this:

```
              a 
             aba
            abcba
           abcdcba
          abcdedcba
         abcdefedbca
        abcdefgfedcba
       abcdefghgfedcba
      abcdefghihgfedcba
     abcdefghijihgfedcba
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
```

However I am stuck with the code. I managed to write the part that can create each line but I do not know how to to repeat this process and make the lines longer. This is what I have so far.

```
def pyramid():
    for middle_letter in range(ord("a"), ord("o")+1):
        for letter in range(ord("a"), ord(middle_letter)+1):
            print chr(letter),
        for letter in reversed(range(ord("a"), ord(middle_letter))):
            print chr(letter),
        middle_letter += 1

pyramid()
```

I tried to repeat this process as long as the letter in the middle of each line is between 'a' and 'o'. The middle_letter should start as 'a' and after each line it should go one value up (so b,c,d..) This part does not work but how can I make it work?

Comment: You are already looping through the middle letters with the for loop, you don't need to increase the middle_letter manually. Do either manually or through the for loop. Notice couple more errors in the code. What error did you get ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 8, in <module>
    pyramid()
  File "...", line 3, in pyramid
    for letter in range(ord("a"), ord(middle_letter)+1):
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: ord(middle_letter) fails as middle_letter is an integer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can just add the "space", dynamically

```
#to use the code in python2, import the modern print() functionality
from __future__ import print_function

first_letter = 'a'
last_letter = 'o'

def pyramid():
    for middle_letter in range(ord(first_letter), ord(last_letter)+1):
        space =(ord(last_letter)+1-middle_letter)
        print(' '*space, end='')
        for letter in range(ord(first_letter), (middle_letter)+1):
            print(chr(letter), end='')
        for letter in reversed(range(ord(first_letter), (middle_letter))):
            print(chr(letter), end='')
        print('')
        middle_letter += 1

pyramid()
```

Output:

```
               a
              aba
             abcba
            abcdcba
           abcdedcba
          abcdefedcba
         abcdefgfedcba
        abcdefghgfedcba
       abcdefghihgfedcba
      abcdefghijihgfedcba
     abcdefghijkjihgfedcba
    abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba
   abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba
  abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
```