# Python 2.7 - Print a pyramid made of letters with given amount of layers

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is almost the same as [Python - Pyramid of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845247/python-pyramid-of-letters). I want the same output as in that question, a pyramid made of letters. The desired output:

```
              a 
             aba
            abcba
           abcdcba
          abcdedcba
         abcdefedbca
        abcdefgfedcba
       abcdefghgfedcba
      abcdefghihgfedcba
     abcdefghijihgfedcba
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
```

The code the OP provides in that question is:

```
def pyramid():
    for middle_letter in range(ord("a"), ord("o")+1):
        for letter in range(ord("a"), ord(middle_letter)+1):
            print chr(letter),
        for letter in reversed(range(ord("a"), ord(middle_letter))):
            print chr(letter),
        middle_letter += 1

pyramid()
```

This code doesn't provide the wanted output. The function in the code also doesn't use any parameters. The answer that's been given to that question imports the modern print() functionality, but I'm not allowed to do that. I'm not allowed to use any import functions, and I have to stick to python 2.7.
The requirements are that I have to use function(s) with parameter(s), the pyramid's desired outcome must have 15 levels and the screen width is 80 characters.

I tried making a function with a parameter that prints a letter in the middle of the screen with the range of 15, and I can now print one single letter in the middle of a line, but I can't figure out how to make the step from a to aba to abcba etc.

```
def level_center(letter):
    for i in range(15):
        middle = letter.center(80)
        print middle
level_center('b')
```

With my code, the output I get is:

```
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b                                        
                                       b
```

I am aware that with my current function, calling level_center() will only print one single letter on each level. But I have no clue where to go from here.

How can the other OPs code or my code be improved in such a way that I get the desired outcome while sticking to the requirements(using functions with parameters, screen width 80 characters, 15 layers, has to work without an import function (from **future** import print_function line))?

Comment: Your first code snippet does not run. First of all your prints have "," at the end. Secondly, your `middle_letter` variable is not actually a letter but rather an integer so `ord(middle_letter)` is not defined. Lastly, I suggest you post the expected outputs and what outputs you are seeing to further guide the SO community in helping you.

Comment: I don't understand how this is not a duplicate of the linked question. You want the same output, and the code you've shown is exactly the code from the other question. If instead you want to know how to adapt the *answer* from that question to work without a `from __future__ import print_function` line, then that could be a valid question (though it's pretty trivial: `print(whatever, end='')` is equivalent to `print whatever,` with a trailing comma).

Comment: @Blckknght I will edit my post now in order to make my question more clear.

Comment: @Blckknght I not only want to know how to adapt the answer from that question to work without a from __future__ import print_function line, I also need to know how to add parameter(s) to the function, since no parameters are given by the other post's OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think works best.

## Code

```
def pyramid(alphabet, layer=1):
  while layer <=15: #  alphabet[:15] goes 0 to 14
    temp_alphabet = alphabet[:layer]
    pyramid_layer = ''.join([letter for letter in temp_alphabet] + [letter for letter in reversed(temp_alphabet[:-1])])
    print('{:^32}'.format(pyramid_layer))
             
    layer+=1
        
alphabet = list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))
pyramid(alphabet)
```

## Explanation:

1. `alphabet` is a list of the alphabet characters which is passed to the function.
2. Loop until the 15th character => 'o'.
3. store a temporary alphabet up to the corresponding `layer` - dynamically changes in the while loop.
4. create 2 lists using list comprehension. First does letters forward, second does backwards excluding the last letter to avoid repetition. Add these lists and `' '.join( )` to form a string (**corresponding to the layer**) where each character is separated by a space.
5. Format the **layer string** to be centered in a field that is 32 units wide and print. This ensures that the layers are centered to form a pyramid. You can choose any value of units to use for the width.
6. Increment the layer variable to eventually break out of the while loop.

## Output:

```
               a                
              aba               
             abcba              
            abcdcba             
           abcdedcba            
          abcdefedcba           
         abcdefgfedcba          
        abcdefghgfedcba         
       abcdefghihgfedcba        
      abcdefghijihgfedcba       
     abcdefghijkjihgfedcba      
    abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba     
   abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba    
  abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba   
 abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
```

Comment: @lenik see the edit if that makes you happy, hopefully you can now up-vote my solution as it actually provides substance rather than nit picky things like you pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation per step. I, however, have one question. I tried playing around with the code to see how that would change the output. In "([letter for letter in temp_alphabet] + [letter for letter in reversed(temp_alphabet[:-1])])", if I change the 'letter' that comes before the 'for' to anything else, it doesn't work anymore (for both the normal alphabet and the reversed). However, if I change both 'letter's in only the normal or only the reversed part, it still works. Why does the word (letter) needs to be the same before ánd after "for"?

Comment: `[i for i in x]` loops through all the items in `x` using a temporary variable `i` and stores those items `i` in a list (one by one). Thus, the variables before and after the for loop match since you want each item in `x` to be stored. This is the same as saying `list_ = []; for i in x:; list_.append(i)` (I used ; to indicate new line here). This is why if you change either one of the variables before or after the for loop it will fail. Generally speaking, list comprehension is much more efficient. For more details see: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation, I feel like I have a better understanding of it now!

Comment: @Wiu if my response helped you, please consider upvoting and/or giving me a ✅

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as chars
>>> def pyramid(N) :
...     return [ ' ' * (N-i-1) + chars[:i+1] + ''.join(reversed(chars[:i])) for i in range(N)]
... 
>>> for p in pyramid(15) : print p
... 
              a
             aba
            abcba
           abcdcba
          abcdedcba
         abcdefedcba
        abcdefgfedcba
       abcdefghgfedcba
      abcdefghihgfedcba
     abcdefghijihgfedcba
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
>>>
```